# How can I Get the properties of T from IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method that returns an IQueryable of T.  Using Reflection I am getting the return type of the method which is the IQueryable of T. I would like to use Reflection to give me all of the properties of T, but when I use the following code, I get no properties:

```
        //Get return type of method and then get its Public properties
        var returnType = methodInfo.ReturnType; // returns typeof(IQueryable<T>)
        var returnTypePropertyInfos = returnType.GetProperties();
        var propertySpecs = returnTypePropertyInfos.Select(returnTypePropertyInfo => new VPropertySpec()
        {
            PropertyName = returnTypePropertyInfo.Name, PropertyType = returnTypePropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: try this .. typeof(T).GetProperties();

Comment: How are you creating the MethodInfo?

Comment: [MSDN on subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172334(v=vs.110).aspx) reading this I found that [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx) has an example of what you are looking for (maybe)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the type of property is `IQueryable<T>` you can do:

```
returnTypePropertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties();
```

Comment: Sorry, did you mean next statement? var returnTypePropertyInfos = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties(); Otherwise I didn't get it.

Comment: The solution is what ntl said. var returnTypePropertyInfos = returnType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties();  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How I would have done it with LINQ:

```
var propertySpect = 
  from argument in methodInfo.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments()
  from property in argument.GetProperties()
  select new VPropertySpec() {
    PropertyName = property.Name, PropertyType = property.PropertyType.Name,
    // Maybe add for multiple generic arguments: GenericArgument = argument,
  };
```